# when I write date 25 JAN 2015 from date-picker then it takes date like 25 DEC 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, model-view-controller, datepicker

This  is My datepicker function

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    rtl: App.isRTL(),
    format: "dd M yyyy",
    showMeridian: true,
    autoclose: true,
    pickerPosition: (App.isRTL() ? "bottom-right" : "bottom-left"),
    todayBtn: true
});
```

This Is my Textbox

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m.DateFrom, 
    String.Format(
        "{0:dd MMM yyyy}", 
        Model.DateFrom.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
    ), 
    new { @class = "clshader clsdate form-control"}
)

<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn default date-set" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

So when I write date 25 JAN 2015 from date-picker using above, it takes date as 25 DEC 2015.

Comment: Please help me... i try many way but no one working.. so please help me

Comment: Not very fromiliar with this datepicker, but perhaps the `String.Format` from the textbox should be 2 M's instead of 3?